# PHP __DIR__ or __FILE__ symlinked

Tags: php

Using `__DIR__` and `__FILE__` constants do not work in a symlinked situation.  What is the workaround for this?

For example:

I have a file:

```
/home/me/modules/myfile.php
```

It is symlinked to:

```
/var/www/project/app/myfile.php
```

from in `/home/me/modules/myfile.php` i need to include a file that is located in `/var/www/project`

EDIT

To the suggestions of using realpath() - unfortunately this does not work.

```
var_dump(__DIR__);
var_dump(realpath(__DIR__));
```

both return exactly the same filepath

Comment: [`realpath()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)

Comment: odd, realpath() returns false and the file definately exists

Comment: `realpath()` of _what_ returns false?  `realpath(__DIR__)`

Comment: Excuse my last comment it was me being stupid.  But, realpath does not actually use the symlinked directory.  So it doesnt work unforunately

Comment: The following discussion may help you resolve the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221771/how-do-you-get-php-symlinks-and-file-to-work-together-nicely

Comment: Just to make it clear: you need directory where symlink is located, not directory of actual file?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller yes exactly

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried the following?

`dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])`

In your case this will return: `/var/www/project/app`

Comment: This only works assuming PHP is running through a web server like Apache, not on the command line.

Comment: Not true. This works regardless of whether you're using a Web Server of Console. It's still going through a Server / SAPI -- in terms of a console, it will go through fpm-cgi rather than apache-cgi, for example. I have tested this and `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` definitely works.

Comment: @emma.fn2 $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] returns file path passed as argument to php, not full path to file

Comment: This will fail to return the correct file path if you use this inside an included PHP file that is in a subfolder

Comment: Using `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is mostly an equivalent to `realpath("./")` so is pretty much useless in a situation Drake describes. Example would be including a `config.php` from `test` directory. Where in the config you need to get scripts root.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`realpath()`](http://php.net/realpath) function to expand symbolic links. My recommendation, however, would be to not use symlinks like this. (Add `/var/www/project/app`, or an appropriate parent directory, to your PHP include path instead.)

Comment: Im afraid realpath doesnt give me the symlinked location either

Comment: [`readlink()`](http://php.net/readlink) maybe? If not, I'm at a loss.

Comment: @duskwuff see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771021/php-dir-or-file-symlinked#comment18933995_13771021 OP wants opposite effect to realpath and readlink

Comment: In that case, that isn't possible. There isn't even a unique answer -- there may be any number of symbolic links which all point to the same file.