# echo __FILE__ in file from folder alias

Tags: php, bash, file, unix, alias

I create a folder alias via `ln -s`:

```
ln -s "/Users/kolya/Documents/Dropbox/Develop/WordPress/Plugins/bbPress Permalinks/plugin/" bbpress-pemalinks
```

And put them into the local server to `/Users/kolya/Sites/wp.local/html/wp-content/plugins/`.

In file `/Users/kolya/Sites/wp.local/html/wp-content/plugins/bbpress-permalinks/plugin.php` I have `echo __FILE__;`.

And this script echo:

`/Users/kolya/Documents/Dropbox/Develop/WordPress/Plugins/bbPress Permalinks/plugin/plugin.php`

But I want to see:

`/Users/kolya/Sites/wp.local/html/wp-content/plugins/bbpress-permalinks/plugin.php`

How to fix it (Mac OS)?

If I create file by clicking right button on mouse and press "Make Alias" and put alias to `/Users/kolya/Sites/wp.local/html/wp-content/plugins/` folder WordPress not see this alias and I can't activate this plugin.

Comment: can you be more specific ?? ..seems like you want url redirecting

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221771/how-do-you-get-php-symlinks-and-file-to-work-together-nicely), it has an answer to yours.

Comment: Hm. `realpath (__FILE__) = __FILE__` and no differents. `dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])` output _main_ file (not included or required file) - it's `index.php` in WordPress, but not `bbpress-permalinks/plugin.php`.

Comment: `realpath(dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]))` outputs `/Users/kolya/Sites/wp.local/html/`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo realpath(__FILE__);
```

So your path will follow symlinks. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Nope. It still echo /Users/kolya/Documents/Dropbox/Develop/WordPress/Plugins/bbPress Permalinks/plugin/plugin.php (path to my Dropbox folder, not server path). Maybe Apache or PHP config required?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I thought you looking for realpath, not symlink. From [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) : Since PHP 4.0.2, `__FILE__` always contains an absolute path with symlinks resolved whereas in older versions it contained relative path under some circumstances. That is not good idea but you can try to work with `exec('pwd')` (works in terminal). Or use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` from Apache (if you use it).

Comment: Maybe some configs in PHP returns it back?

Comment: I do not know any config option to fix it. But [this link](http://chrismarslender.com/2012/07/29/wordpress-register_activation_hook-doesnt-work-with-symlinks/) looks like a solution.

Comment: Yep. Similar issue but echo basename(dirname(__FILE__)).'/'.basename(__FILE__) outputs plugin/plugin.php