# How can I fetch the parent directory of the current symlinked directory?

Tags: php

I would like to get an absolute path of the current script which is actually symlinked.

The `__FILE__` always points to the real file and not the symlink, while `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` points to the symlink.

I would like to go up the directory tree of the `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` but appending the `/..` and invoking `realpath` navigates up the directory tree of the actual file.

Here's the code I'm running:

```
print dirname(__FILE__);
print '<br />';
print realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..');
print '<br />';
print $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
print '<br />';
print realpath(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) . '/..');
```

The code above outputs:

```
/Users/mridang/Hello/Application
/Users/mridang/Hello
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/1609/modules/mymodule/ctrl.php
/Users/mridang/Hello
```

How can I navigate up the directory of the symlink without resolving the symlink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know you can use the native PHP function [`readlink`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readlink.php). This should resolve symlinks.

You can also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221771/how-do-you-get-php-symlinks-and-file-to-work-together-nicely) from StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use readlink($path) to read the target of symbolic link. You can check if it is a symbolic link with is_link:

Examples:

```
<?php
    if (is_link($link)) {
       echo(readlink($link));
    }

    echo readlink(dirname(__FILE__));
?>
```